# Why does my MacOS no longer use the keychain for SVN credentials?

Tags: svn, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

### Problem description

I used to be able to update my svn repositories via the command line simply by typing:

`$ svn up`

I believe that username was taken from `~/.subversion/auth` and the password was taken from the keychain. I checked and this information is still there. However, since recently SVN started to prompt me for the password:

`$ svn up
Updating '.':
Authentication realm: <https://svn.domain.com:443> Subversion repository
Password for 'username': ***`

In addition, it would then tell me:

`ATTENTION! Your password for authentication realm [...] can only be stored to disk unencrypted! You are advised to configure your system so that Subversion can store passwords encrypted, if possible. See the documentation for details.`

I tried setting `password-stores = keychain` in `~/.subversion/config` but this did not help.

### Question

Does anybody know what's going on here? How can I configure my SVN so that it uses the keychain again?

I should note that I have installed SVN via homebrew. The currently installed version is 1.9.4. I believe it was upgraded only recently, so this might have to do something with it. Besides that, I am running macOS 10.13.1.

Answer (score 4):

Just deleting it from keychain worked for me FYI. Future visitors may try that first before deleting ~/.subversion/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I solved it by deleting my `~/.subversion`folder AND the passwords stored in my KeyChain for the domain `svn.domain.com`

Hope this helps.